# Referencing another sheet that isn't named yet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write an Excel Macro that will create a new sheet, then I will name the new sheet. I then want a table on a summary sheet to pull information from the newly created sheet to certain cells in a Summary sheet. This is the code I currently have written:

```
Dim Newname As String
Newname = InputBox("Name for new worksheet?")
If Newname <> "" Then
    Sheets("PumpTag#").Copy Before:=Sheets("PumpTag#")
    ActiveSheet.Name = Newname
End If
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range("C4").Select
Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
```

So far this makes the new sheet, names it and takes me back to the summary sheet as I would like and selects the cell I want. I am struggling to get it to pull the information I want though. When I recorded a macro this is the code it came up with for that line:

```
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "='Sheet (2)'!RC[2]:RC[5]"
```

I have tried using this line of code but replacing Sheet (2) with Newname. I think it is either the fact that the name of the new sheet isn't Newname so the ' ' is messing with that or that the variable Newname is no longer really in use because it has been assigned a name when filling it out. Any ideas?

I want it to populate the information I put in the selected cell in the new sheet into the cell on the summary sheet.